# What is wrong with my Saving System ? I'm trying to use json to save objects positions rotations scaling to files

Tags: unity, c#

This script is attached to empty GameObject and for testing I dragged two Cubes to the objectsToSave array.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] objectsToSave;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SaveSystem.Init();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        SaveObject saveObject = new SaveObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Length; i++)
        {
            saveObject.position = objectsToSave[i].position;
            saveObject.scaling = objectsToSave[i].localScale;
            saveObject.rotation = objectsToSave[i].rotation;

            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveObject);
            SaveSystem.Save(json);
        }
    }

    public void LoadSingleRecentFile()
    {
        string saveString = SaveSystem.LoadSingleRecentFile();

        if (saveString != null)
        {
            SaveObject saveObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveObject>(saveString);

            transform.position = saveObject.position;
            transform.localScale = saveObject.scaling;
            transform.rotation = saveObject.rotation;
        }
    }

    public void LoadMultipleFiles()
    {
        List<string> savedStrings = SaveSystem.LoadMultipleFiles();

        for(int i = 0; i < savedStrings.Count; i++)
        {
            SaveObject saveObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveObject>(savedStrings[i]);

            objectsToSave[i].position = saveObject.position;
            objectsToSave[i].localScale = saveObject.scaling;
            objectsToSave[i].rotation = saveObject.rotation;
        }
    }

    public class SaveObject
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public Vector3 scaling;
        public Quaternion rotation;
    }
}
```

This class make the saving to the file/s :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    private static readonly string SAVE_FOLDER = Application.dataPath + "/save_";
    public static void Init()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(SAVE_FOLDER))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(SAVE_FOLDER);
        }
    }

    public static void Save(string saveString)
    {
        int saveNumber = 1;
        if (!File.Exists(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + saveNumber + ".txt"))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + saveNumber + ".txt", saveString);
        }
        while (File.Exists(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + saveNumber + ".txt"))
        {
            saveNumber++;
        }
        File.WriteAllText(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + saveNumber + ".txt", saveString);
    }

    public static string LoadSingleRecentFile()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(SAVE_FOLDER);
        FileInfo[] saveFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
        FileInfo mostRecentFile = null;
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in saveFiles)
        {
            if (mostRecentFile == null)
            {
                mostRecentFile = fileInfo;
            }
            else
            {
                if (fileInfo.LastWriteTime > mostRecentFile.LastWriteTime)
                {
                    mostRecentFile = fileInfo;
                }
            }
        }

        if (mostRecentFile != null)
        {
            string saveString = File.ReadAllText(mostRecentFile.FullName);
            return saveString;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static List<string> LoadMultipleFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(SAVE_FOLDER);
        FileInfo[] saveFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
        List<string> savedFiles = new List<string>();
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in saveFiles)
        {
            string savedFile = File.ReadAllText(fileInfo.FullName);
            if(savedFile != null)
            {
                savedFiles.Add(savedFile);
            }
        }

        return savedFiles;
    }
}
```

In the editor in the scene I have 3 buttons one for saving one for loading a single saved file and one for loading all the saved files for all the saved objects in this case two cubes :

[image: Save system scene]

The problems I'm facing :

- I can click the Save button many times and it will keep creating new text files even if the cubs didn't change any position rotation or scaling. The logic is to enable the saving button only when the two cubes or one of the cubes change position or rotation or scaling or all the three.
- When clicking on the Save button I'm not getting any errors but when clicking the Load Single button it does nothing when clicking the Load Multiple button it's changing one of the cubes and put it on the same position of the other cube and throw this error :

ndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
SaveLoad.LoadMultipleFiles () (at Assets/My Scripts/SaveLoad.cs:51)

Line 51 in the SaveLoad script is :

```
objectsToSave[i].position = saveObject.position;
```

What I'm trying to do is :

- When clicking the Save button save all the objects in the List objectsToSave position,rotation,scaling each object in the List to have his own text file.
- Enable saving only if one of the objects to save changed position,rotation,scaling one of those or all the three.
- When clicking the Load Multiple button load all the saved positions,rotations,scaling changes made for all the objects to save in the List.
- When clicking Load Single then load the last changed object to save made in the List the most recent changed object in the List.

The idea is later to extend the class for other objects like cameras and others:

```
public class SaveObject
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public Vector3 scaling;
        public Quaternion rotation;
    }
```

For the button logic enable true false if one of the objects or all of the objects has changed I added in the top of the SaveLoad script :

```
public Button saveButton;
```

Then in Update :

```
private void Update()
    {
        foreach(Transform objectToSave in objectsToSave)
        {
            if(objectToSave.hasChanged)
            {
                saveButton.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

but what if the List objectsToSave will have a lot of objects ? The loop in the Update might get slower. and how should I check if all the objects has bot changed then keep or set the button to be enable false ?

Comment: "The logic is to enable the saving button only when the two cubes or one of the cubes change position or rotation or scaling or all the three." — Where do you express that logic in your code? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @DMGregory Right, Updated my question with what I did with the button so far.

Comment: Did you you [read the documentation for Transform.hasChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html) to check whether it does what you want?